# Fetching Maximum Id into variable using Max() function not working in MySQL store procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, null, max

Declare:

```
Maxid varchar(11) default null;
Select ifnull(max(employeeID),0) into @Maxid from employees where mid(employeeID,1,2) = '04';
```

I want to fetch the maximum Id of EmployeeID from employees table using sub string of first two digit of Employee ID.

The above select query, if to be executed separately(in MySQL workbench query browser), gives the perfect result, however in store procedure it results as 0(zero) means null value.

- MaxId has same datatype as of employeeId
- Datatype of maxid was also changed to integer but same 0 result.

Any idea why it is not getting correct result in store procedure ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the DECLARE statement before your local variable declaration and you're mixing up Maxid and @Maxid. Try this:

```
DECLARE Maxid varchar(11) default null;
Select ifnull(max(employeeID),0) into Maxid from employees where mid(employeeID,1,2) = '04';
```

Comment: Thanks I tried the mentioned code but still the same result 0.
I tried even this code but 0 or null in result :
Declare MaxId bigint;
(Select max(convert(mid(employeeID,4,8),unsigned integer)) as MaxId from employees
where mid(employeeid,1,2) = '04');
select MaxId into @MaxId from temp;
Drop table temp;

The employeeid is like this '04-00000008'

Comment: Solved: I had declared EmployeeId variable as well and the field Employeeid in table employees was conflicting with it .By changing the name of variable solved the problem .